# ASPSmartUpload v3.2

Tags: asp-classic

I have the unfortunate task of fixing a legacy ASP site that was migrated to Windows Server 2003, and I know nothing about ASP.  The main issue appears to be with ASPSmartUpload, of which I have version 2.3 installed.  According to http://foradvice.net/smart_upload_faq.htm:

> FAQ: does aspSmartUpload work on
>   Windows 2003 server ?
>
> Yes, last versions of aspSmartUpload
>   work fine on the Windows 2003 server.
>   If you upgrade your OS and used an old
>   version of aspSmartUpload, you have to
>   download and setup aspSmartUpload
>   3.2+.

Of course, aspsmart.com doesn't respond and any Google result for "aspsmartupload 3.2" points to the dead link.  The latest version I can find anywhere is v3.0, on some dodgy-looking DLL download site.

What is the best way to resolve this, or can anyone provide a working link to version 3.2 of ASPSmartUpload?  Thanks!

Comment: A link on how to install that dll: http://schoening.it/blog/post/2010/11/16/How-to-install-ASPSmartUpload-on-Windows-7-Vista-Server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We searched for quite a while before finding these dlls.

Here is the link for the [ASPSMARTUPLOAD.DLL Usage](http://www.umbrellastudio.com/how-to/aspsmartupload-dll/) page that tells you how to install it and a link for downloading version 3.3.

From what I understand, windows server 2008 requires version 3.2 or higher, but we couldn't find version 3.2.  I believe version 3.3 will work the same.

One other item, we had to get msvbvm50.dll VB Runtimes for this to work on windows server 2008.

Once these files were registered the server restarted we got past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I have a copy of the original v3.3 distribution.
I've shared it [here](http://1drv.ms/1BhbuD5).